# Virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have found this problem only lately, apparently all my Ubuntu VMs stopped accessing internet. Host is Windows 10, connected either via Ethernet or WiFi, Vmware Workstation 12.5.6, network config in Vmware is NAT.
My Ubuntu VMs need a static address, I cannot use DHCP, here's the output of ifconfig:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f6:c9:67:3d  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:91:eb:b8  
          inet addr:192.168.72.179  Bcast:192.168.72.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe91:ebb8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:39862 (39.8 KB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:64884 (64.8 KB)  TX bytes:64884 (64.8 KB)
and this is the content of /etc/network/interfaces:
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.72.179
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.72.2
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.222.220, 8.8.8.8
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried to ping 8.8.8.8, Destination host is unreachable. 
Anything else I can check?